# MFC Application: print XML file based on XSLT style sheet

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am currently trying to use XSLT to be my print report template in a MFC application. All the data is well structured in a XML file. Does anyone know how to print/print preview such styled sheet from MFC code? Any good tutorials or sample source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done this in the past, I've relied on using Internet Explorer to do the actual display.  You should be able to load an ActiveX Web Browser control and have that render for you.

It isn't MFC, but the following code project should be a good place to start.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9270/Utilize-Internet-Explorer-to-display-reports-using

Comment: Thanks mmodahl, I will try to insert an ActiveX control.

Comment: Here is a good source that I found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3919/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-simplified.

Comment: Also for generating HTML from xml and xslt, here is a good example using MSXML: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c4565